# Colour-categorised density scatterplots

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I need to admit that I am pretty new to R and programming in general.

I am looking to create a density scatterplot. I have around 350 data points and only 27 unique x,y values. I would like it take the shape of what smoothScatter does with the only difference being that I would like the data points to take the colour which would reflect the absolute density (like, 1-5 green; 2-10, blue; 11-20, red; etc.), not how intense the colour is. Essentially, sharp and coloured points is what I am after

This is what it looks like before colouring:

[image]

Can you please help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: This is a scatter plot, but a density plot is something else. Are you asking for color to reflect how many data points reside in each position? If that's the case, we'll need some data to provide advice on that.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, indeed, I'm asking for colour to reflect how many data points reside in each position. There are is an independent variable Grade and a dependent variable Corrected. The Improv Variable is Corrected - Grade (Improv=Corrected - Grade). Want to show which original grades improve the most upon the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using the standard plot function and `mtcars` where the color reflects the model of the car.

```
attach(mtcars)
cars <- mtcars
cars$model <- as.factor(rownames(cars))
plot(cars$mpg, cars$wt, col = cars$model, pch = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this :) It'd be really helpful if I could manually categorise the data points regarding their frequency. Would prefer R to count how many data points exist at a certain location and then colour it accordingly.

Comment: This is a completely different analysis known as clustering.  Here is a reference: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html

Comment: Thanks, now I know that I need to go towards k-means. Will try to figure this out (a chemist by education and now in HR so it may be tough... ). Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this?

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- data.frame(x = runif(37), y = runif(37))
xy <- round(xy, 1)
rp <- sample(1:30, size = nrow(xy), replace = TRUE)
xy <- xy[rp, ]
xy$colors <- cut(rp, 3)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y, color = colors)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y, color = colors)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point()+
  geom_density_2d(h = 0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my slow response, needed to go through every single function you mentioned to understand what's going on :) I am afraid this is not what I would be look for. Would it be helpful if I attached a CSV file?

Comment: @PiotrWojciechowski you need to adjust the cut function to produce bins you are after...